# USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 motherboard headers compatibility

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-3, headers

I have a [Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4153#sp) motherboard which comes with 2 USB 2.0 internal headers (2*5-1 pins) and 3 USB 3.0 internal headers (2*10-1 pins). The two USB 2.0 headers are occupied, as are 2 of the three 3.0 headers.

I have an additional internal USB 2.0 cable that needs to be plugged in. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/516919/can-i-safely-connect-a-usb-2-0-1-1-internal-pin-block-to-a-usb3-0-motherboard-he) seems to say that the 2.0 connector will not and should not be connected directly into the USB 3.0 header. Can I still use the remaining USB 3.0 header? And if so how (i.e. what kind of adapter)? At this time, I do not feel comfortable playing with the individual wiring.

I also have a PCI USB expansion card which has an internal USB *plug*. Could this be somehow used to connect the internal USB 2.0 cable, and what kind of adapter would let me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they're physically incompatible on the motherboard side, but there's very little stopping a USB 2.0 device or connector being used with a USB 3.0 header with an appropriate adaptor - [a quick google search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=USB%203.0%20male%20header%20to%20usb%202.0%20female%20header&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) reveals there's quite a few appropriate adaptors with a USB 3.0 female to USB 2.0 male adaptor.

If you want a USB type A Male to usb male header, for use with that PCI cards [try this search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=USB%20type%20A%20to%20USB%20male&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#client=firefox-a&hs=L9H&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=USB%20type%20A%20to%20USB%20header%20male&oq=USB%20type%20A%20to%20USB%20header%20male&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30.4275.5726.0.5924.7.7.0.0.0.1.126.566.6j1.7.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.JVuzqJTRrNs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk&fp=174d9f11960d1e56&biw=1600&bih=848). You should be able to plug in the header on the device side to the male header, and plug that right in.

So yes, *physical* incompatibility aside, USB 2.0's pin out is a subset of USB 3.0, and with the appropriate parts, you can, in fact, plug in a USB 2.0 plug into a USB 3.0 header on the motherboard.

Comment: Just to note, this isn't a LMGFY answer. I prefer google searches for this since specific sites may change, and knowing *what* to look for is more important here.