# Usb 2.0 header into 3.0 on case

Tags: usb

I have a USB 2.0 header on my motherboard so can I plug that into my 3.0 port on the front of my  case? I'm not sure if it'll work and don't want to spend £100 on my case and motherboard and have it not work since it is my first,budget build.

Comment: Similar question.  http://superuser.com/questions/587895/usb-3-0-and-usb-2-0-motherboard-headers-compatibility?rq=1

Comment: oh I misunderstood the whole question :) thanks @Moab

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you should use a cable to adapt it.

A USB2 and USB3 header differ, as USB3 has more pins.

[image]

Image courtesy of [here](http://www.directron.com/frontusb3guide.html)

You can get a cable similar to the following:

[image]

As USB3 is backwards compatible and has a pin out compatible with USB2 devices, it's just a case of matching the correct pins on the header to the pins on the cable. Do a search for `USB3 to USB2 Header Cable Adapter`, it'll be a 19 pin to 9 pin adapter (Maybe listed as 20 to 10, but one pin will likely be missing to be used as a key), there should be plenty of results.

Comment: Wouldn't say it has the same pinout that means something else to us elec engineers

Comment: @Ramhound Please adjust as required, a compatible pin layout perhaps? I'm not an electrical engineer :)